# Use Orchestrate.io with a basic Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic application running with ruby on rails. I use sqlite3 for development and postgres for production. I recently got access to Orchestrate.io and their student tier.

I would like to know how I could possibly use this with my application. I'm not even sure this is possible. My app is really simple (add-edit-delete). But it would be interesting to have a go at using the tools.

Mostly because I cannot find an efficient and free rails db text search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use Orchestrate as the backend for a Rails application.

A few different options:

- The [Orchestrate-Ruby client](https://github.com/orchestrate-io/orchestrate-ruby) has both a method client & object client. Although the object client is still considered a work-in-progress, the method client provides a solid interface for connecting to the Orchestrate API.
- Use an http library (such as **rest-client** or **faraday**) to make calls to the Orchestrate API.
- There's also the [Orchestrate-Rails gem](https://github.com/jimcar/orchestrate-rails). Your mileage may vary with this (last updated in April).

---

To use Orchestrate as the only backend (no postgres/mysql), I've found the best approach is to disable ActiveRecord:

When creating a new application, you can use `-O` to skip ActiveRecord:

```
rails new my_app -O
```

For existing applications:

**1. Remove database adapter gems from your Gemfile (pg, mysql2, sqlite3, etc.)**

**2. Change your `config/application.rb`**

Remove `require 'rails/all` line and require frameworks you want to use, for example:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

**3. Delete your `database.yml` file, `db/schema.rb` and migrations (if any)**

**4. Delete migration check in `test/test_helper.rb`**

**5. Delete any ActiveRecord configuration from your `config/environments` files (this is what is causing your error)**

If you run into problems/errors, stack trace should give you sufficient information on what you need to change. You might for example have some ActiveRecord configuration in your initializers.

---

With the Orchestrate-Ruby client, you can define a model like so:

```
class Foo < Orchestrate::Collection
  ...
end
```

I'm still undecided on what the best approach for defining the Application object is, but one way I've done it is by making a global object with an initializer:

```
# /config/initializers/orchestrate.rb

$App = Orchestrate::Application.new(ENV['ORCHESTRATE_KEY']) # using dotenv gem
$App = Orchestrate::Application.new('your_key_here') # without dotenv
```

From here, you can then access the $App object in your controllers (to initialize the collection object):

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.new($App, "foos").each
  end
end
```

Leveraging model concerns might be a better way to share the Application object/API key between models. Or you could roll your own classes on top of the method client.

Hope this helps!

I'll be looking into how to accomplish this in a more 'Railsy' way.

EDIT: also, textacular is a ruby gem which provides full-text search and indexing for postgres

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation (I know you should avoid thank you comments but that's a lot of writing!

Comment: No problem, if you get stuck or have any questions don't hesitate to ask!